# ng repeat not rendering on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page rendering a ng-repeat from data requested via an http.get, however it's not loading the data from the get request. What am I missing here?

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-show="isLoggedIn()">
<div class="row images">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="img in imgs">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="{{img.url}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('imginterestApp')
  .controller('GuestPageCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $scope.userName = $routeParams.userId;
    console.log($scope.userName);
    $scope.imgs = [];

    $http.get('/api/images/').success(function(data){
        data.forEach(function(image){
        if(image.owner === $scope.userName) {
          $scope.imgs.push(image);
        }
      })
      console.log($scope.imgs);
    });
  });
```

Comment: if(image.owner === $scope.userName)...what is this...

Comment: @vijaykani I'm filtering out the users images by matching the owners name with a passed argument. The function works fine after a few tests. The issue I'm having is with the ng-repeat.

Comment: Is something shown in the console for your `console.log($scope.imgs);` ? Meaning that are there actually items in the scope?

Comment: Try adding $scope.$apply() after the image push to force a manual update.

Comment: @vonv. yes that is working fine.

Comment: scope.$apply is really not needed for this specific scenario. @pdotsani perhaps you overlooked it, have you checked that your `container-fluid` div is actually shown?

Comment: @DanielNalbach Didn't work =( .

Comment: @vonv. ahh overlooked it... the ng-show was hiding my container! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enclose your get request for getting images into function and call it. This will ensure that your imgs array will contains the images data.

```js
angular.module('imginterestApp')
  .controller('GuestPageCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $scope.userName = $routeParams.userId;
    console.log($scope.userName);
    $scope.imgs = [];
  
    $scope.init = function () {
  $http.get('/api/images/').success(function(data){
        data.forEach(function(image){
        if(image.owner === $scope.userName) {
          $scope.imgs.push(image);
        }
      })
      console.log($scope.imgs);
    });
 }
 
 $scope.init();
});
```